# jquery UI autocomplate options not presented until the second search

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, user-interface

Here's my code:

```
$("#hifind-find").keyup(function(){

  var val = $(this).val();

  if (val.length > 1) {
    var posturl = '/hifind/jquery_ui/autocomplete/'+val;

    $.post(posturl, function(r) { 

      $("#hifind-find").autocomplete({
        source: r,
        delay: 50,
        minLength: 2
      });

      $("#hifind-find").bind('autocompleteselect', function(){
        alert('test');
      });

    }, "json");
  }

});
```

I type a letter in the #hifind-find field.  As expected, nothing happens because the val isn't greater than 1 yet.  I type a second character.  As expected, the post fires and the response in firebug is what I would expect.  But the jquery ui plugin does not show the matching items below the field.  If I then backspace once and then type the second character again, the post fires again and this time the options are presented.  The results are always presented the second *consecutive* time an identical search is conducted.  So...

1. ba (no options presented)
2. Backspace twice, and then...
3. ba ("banana" is presented as an option, and "babe ruth", etc).

But, if I reload, and then...

1. ba (nothing presented)
2. ap (nothing presented)
3. ba (nothing presented)
4. ap (nothing, and so on until I do the same search twice consecutively)

I can see in firebug that the response from the callback is the same every time, and contains the right data.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong. Instead of binding to keyup yourself you should supply a callback to the autocomplete search field.. This way the autocomplete will do caching and what not for you.

See this post: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

For how to better use the autocompleter.

In your example it would look like this:

```
      $("#hifind-find").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          var posturl = '/hifind/jquery_ui/autocomplete/'+request.term;
          $.post(posturl, function(data) { 
             response(data);
          }, "json");
         },
        delay: 50,
        minLength: 2
      });

      $("#hifind-find").bind('autocompleteselect', function(){
        alert('test');
      });
```

I suggest you add a cache to that as described in the post I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

You're turning the component into an autocomplete only after the second keyup.

This makes no sense--why not just follow their demos? It's much easier than you're making it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the keyup event does not wait for the AJAX to return and execute the callback function.  The keyup event completes before the autocomplete source contains any data.  When you do it a second time, the source has already been populated from the previous AJAX call, so it works (sort of).

Comment: I believe you, Dave and Matt are saying the same thing in different ways. You've all got it right. Thx for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because it first needs to be filled, and after that it'll be ready to get chars, so why don't you try to fill it when it first gets a char, so then after the second char it'll be ready...

This code:

```
val.length > 1
```

Should be:

```
val.length > 0
```

Plus I don't think it is a good idea to call a post for every key pressed, it should get the post the fist time so it can fill the autocomplete object, and after that it should use that object...